# Short sci-fi animation about a robot waking up in a post-apocalyptic world

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, animation, short-film

There was this short animated film (<15 min) I watched once, I think on Youtube, and I'm trying to identify it. It was made relatively recently, most likely within the past decade. The details are:

- A small dinosaur-like robot wakes up in a forest, and explores a post-apocalyptic world where all the humans are gone and everything is overgrown.
- The exploration of the world is interposed by flashbacks to the past, where the robot's inventor is creating a video log about his creation, and his hopes and dreams for it.
- The film ends on a scene where the small robot explores a city and stumbles upon a scene where the overgrown wreckage of a much larger and dangerous-looking version of the small robot is preserved in a scene of combat, with several ancient human corpses around it. Meanwhile, the audio of the scientist's vlog continues, finishing over the scene with the words "Some day, you'll change the world."

Comment: Can you remember what style of animation this was? Western cartoon? Anime? Etc.?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Definitely more western, although it was a bit unique. It predominantly used flat colors. lots of grays and bright greens for the outside bits. I can't tell from memory whether it was 2D or 3D, probably because it was a style that seemed like both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### "Redone" (2017)

> A small robot awakes many years after a mysterious mass-extinction. Driven only by the fragmented recordings of his creator, he wanders the ruins searching for answers.

The style, story and robot seems to match. (found by searching "animation post-apocalyptic robot dinosaur" on YouTube.)

The end also matches pretty well:

> I know he doesn't look like much now, but, trust me, this little guy, and lots like him, they're going to change the world.

Comment: This seems to match perfectly, nice find and a good first answer here on SFF!

Comment: Oh man, that's it! Thank you!